# Can't hear what the anouncer says

Tags: listening-comprehension

In the video below, I can't understand what the anouncer say introducing the girl. What did he say?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nD4ib9-laGY

> ..17 Jahre alt, die in Hamburg lebt, singt heute für Luxemburg.
>   (die die bekam Zarzein ab auch)? Liebs die bekam grau sein aber auch blau. ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Die Liebe kann zart sein, aber auch wild, die Liebe kann grau sein, aber auch blau."

Comment: Klingt seltsam, aber der Ansager bezieht sich hier auf den Text des Liedes "L'amour est bleu", das Vicky Leandros anschließend singt.